# Function for multi column filtering in Pandas with a loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array, filter

Suppose I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
df = DataFrame({'A' : [True, True, False], 'B' : [1, 1, 2], 'C' : [3, 4, 5]})

|        A |        B |        C |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| True     | 1        | 3        |
| True     | 1        | 4        |
| False    | 2        | 5        |
```

I want write a function that will give a list of columns and their corresponding values as inputs and it will return the filtered list. For example,

```
def pandas_filter(df, columns_list, values_list):
    return df.loc[df[columns_list] == values_list]
```

Continuing on the example, when I write the following code

```
result = pandas_filter(df=df, columns_list=[A, B], values_list=[True, 1])
```

I want to get the following result

```
|        A |        B |        C |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| True     | 1        | 3        |
| True     | 1        | 4        |
```

```
def pandas_filter(df, columns_list, values_list):
    return df.loc[df[columns_list] == values_list]
```

This function returns ValueError("Cannot index with multidimensional key")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to chain your *eq-comparison* (`==`) with [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) to form a *mask* :

```
def pandas_filter(df, columns_list, values_list):
    return df.loc[
        (df[columns_list] == values_list).all(axis=1) # <-- add it here
    ]

result = pandas_filter(df=df, columns_list=["A", "B"], values_list=[True, 1])
```

Output :

```
print(result)

      A  B  C
0  True  1  3
1  True  1  4
```

*Intermediates :*

```
>>> df[columns_list] == values_list
       A      B
0   True   True
1   True   True
2  False  False

>>> (df[columns_list] == values_list).all(axis=1)
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small error in your code because you need to specify column names in columns_list as strings. Also, the == operator does not work with a list of values. You can use the isin() method which allows you to check if a column contains one of the values ​​in the list.

```
def pandas_filter(df, columns_list, values_list):
    conditions = pd.Series(True, index=df.index)
    for col, val in zip(columns_list, values_list):
        conditions = conditions & df[col].isin([val])
    return df.loc[conditions]
```

The isin() method checks whether each value in a column is contained in the corresponding list of values.

Comment: I accepted another answer because it looked simpler but this approach works as well. Thank you!

Comment: Most or all of your six answers here appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.